# CUFFT and FFTW data structures: are cufftComplex and fftwf_complex interchangable?

Tags: cuda, gpu, fft, fftw

I have some code that performs forward and inverse FFTs with FFTW. I'm working on porting some pieces of the code to use NVIDIA CUFFT.

To verify that my CUFFT-based pieces are working properly, I'd like to diff the CUFFT output with the reference FFTW output for a forward FFT. One challenge in implementing this diff is the `complex` data structure in the two libraries: CUFFT has `cufftComplex`, and FFTW has `fftwf_complex`.

Are `cufftComplex` and `fftwf_complex` interchangable (e.g. can I cast the CUFFT data type to be compatible with FFTW)? Or, do I need to do something to convert between the two data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying data structures are just a pair of floats in both cases. You should be able to use the C++ `reinterpret_cast` mechanism to cast a pointer to an host array of `cufftComplex` to `fftwf_complex` and vice versa.

Comment: great! I just tried this out. Looks like we can index into them like this: `fftwf_complex[0]` `fftwf_complex[1]` and `cufftComplex.x` `cufftComplex.y`. I also did some `reinterpret_cast` experiments, and the data matches.